# How to use a single form to collect data for two or more models in Yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2

My problem is to dynamically create forms through jquery.
 The user should be able to dynamically generate inputs such that he can save multiple rows into the corresponding model/table in one go.
Now I don't know how do I generate the `name` attribute for the forms for multiple models. I suppose it should be something like `ModelName[Property][]` (but I would preferably want to do it in 'Yii way' instead of hardcoding the names)

To understand this better, Here I found a similar post in Yii Wiki.

[using a single form to collect data for two or more models](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/)

How can this be modified for Yii2? So that the user should be able to fill in data for all the (dynamically generated) rows and submit them in one go.

Comment: Do you want to add multiple rows for same table or want to submit data for multiple models through one form. ?? Got confused reading the whole post!

Comment: sorry, in fact I could have chose better words. I want to add multiple rows for same table. you got it right! :)

Comment: Your question title is saying something else :)

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/666/handling-tabular-data-loading-and-validation-in-yii-2/) of tabular form for multiple models.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, [Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53935-solved-subforms/page__p__248184#entry248184)

```
public function actionCreate()
{   
    $user = new User;
    $profile = new Profile;

    if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple([$user, $profile])) {

        $user->save(false); // skip validation as model is already validated
        $profile->user_id = $user->id; 
        $profile->save(false); 

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $user->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'user' => $user,
            'profile' => $profile,
        ]);
    }
}
```